# AzureManaged SQL Dump To Blob Container By SqlPackage

Tags: database, azure, sqlcmd

I want to automate **azure managed** sqlserver dump operation. I can dump the data by **sqlpackage** tool. But I couldn't find how to push it to blob container. Also **I don't want to use az-cli** command. Is it possible to manage that process without az-cli ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sqlpackage` tool to dump the data from Azure managed SQL server.

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:Export /ssn:tcp:servername.database.windows.net /sdn:databasename /su:username /sp:password /tf:D:\bacpac\azuredemosql.bacpac(local file path)
```

[image]

Following that, you may upload the data to the blob container using the `AzCopy` v10 command-line tool. The following command may be used to upload the data:

```
azcopy copy "local_file_path" "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername/?<SAS token>" --recursive=true
```

[image]

Comment: Yes but I don't wanna uze az cli tool as I mentioned

Comment: You can directly use portal and upload the file.

Comment: Or you can use ADF to load file from local to blob storage